# Solr indexing but numdocs returned 0

Tags: solr

I have Solr 4.2 setup. The data import runs good and the raw status output is:

**Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 19,162 documents. Deleted 0 documents. (Duration: 24s)
Requests: 1 (0/s), Fetched: 19,162 (798/s), Skipped: 0, Processed: 19,162 (798/s)
Started: less than a minute ago**

It seems like Indexes are fetched, processed and committed.

But the NumDocs field on Overview is still returning 0, and searching using *:* is returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you commited results?
If you are using Solr UI there is a tick-box for that.
If you're making a HTTP call try adding "commit=true"

Solr's [DIH documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Commands) says that default is true, but I think that they changed it around 4.0

Comment: Thanks Fuxi. I checked again by trying manually adding, http://localhost:8983/solr/custom_documents/dataimport?command=full-import&commit=true

Comment: That should do the trick. Or you still can't see any documents?

Comment: No it is still not working. When I do dataimport as verbose, I see it generating uuid and other fields from query, for multiple documents. What I am not getting is whats missing. Let me keep trying and will post here if find solutions. thanks.

Comment: Good luck. What I would try to do: 1. check logs 2. try to add optimize=true, 3. reload the core (possibly searcher have not get reloaded after indexing is done)

Comment: OK so I got this working after added following processor chanin to updateRequestProcessorChain. It looks like below now. <updateRequestProcessorChain name="default-values">
                <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
                        <str name="fieldName">id</str>
                </processor>
                <processor class="solr.RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" />
                <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
                <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
        </updateRequestProcessorChain>